# IE11 Displaying boxes & characters only

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

This issue happens only sometimes on IE11, and gets fixed sometimes via clear cache.
anyone know where to start looking into on this one?

[image]

Comment: Looks like some encoding issue. Any clues in the network panel? Whats the backend doing? Sounds like too vague of a problem for SO.

Comment: only happens on IE11 sometimes, runs behind scurii firewall, normal wordpress theme website. Never seen this issue before so dont know where to start.

Comment: If the issue is related to the specific site then I suggest you go to `View-> Encoding` and make sure that `Unicode(UTF-8)` is selected. If you are able to modify the site code then add this meta tag in the head part. `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`. You can try to save the webpage with `UTF-8` encoding. Sometimes this issue may occur due to non-compatible fonts with the IE 11 browser. You can try to check these things on your side and see if it works. If the issue persists try to provide more information with sample code may help to narrow down the issue.